# Sum columns in pandas having string and number

Tags: pandas

I need to sum column and column b, which contain string in 1st row

```
>>> df
   a  b
0  c  d
1  1  2
2  3  4
>>> df['sum'] = df.sum(1)
>>> df
   a  b sum
0  c  d  cd
1  1  2   3
2  3  4   7
```

I only need to add numeric values and get an output like

```
>>> df
   a  b sum
0  c  d  "dummyString/NaN"
1  1  2   3
2  3  4   7
```

I need to add only some columns

`df['sum']=df['a']+df['b']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

solution if mixed data - numeric with strings:

I think simpliest is convert non numeric values after `sum` by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to `NaN`s:

```
df['sum'] = pd.to_numeric(df[['a','b']].sum(1), errors='coerce')
```

Or:

```
df['sum'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a']+df['b'], errors='coerce')

print (df)
   a  b  sum
0  c  d  NaN
1  1  2  3.0
2  3  4  7.0
```

EDIT:

Solutions id numbers are strings represenation - first convert to numeric and then `sum`:

```
df['sum'] = pd.to_numeric(df['a'], errors='coerce') + pd.to_numeric(df['b'], errors='coerce')
print (df)
   a  b  sum
0  c  d  NaN
1  1  2  3.0
2  3  4  7.0
```

Or:

```
df['sum'] = (df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
                           .sum(axis=1, min_count=1))
print (df)
   a  b  sum
0  c  d  NaN
1  1  2  3.0
2  3  4  7.0
```

Comment: thanks, it works for the simple df like i gave in question, but `df.dtypes` for a and b  are object type, so sum is giving me NaN